# Reverse Geolocation and Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I am creating a map based web site using Openlayers and Openstreet maps. click on the map and fill out a popup form and add a picture. lonlat is captured and a marker appears on the map at that point. currently when you load the page all the entries (markers) are fetched from the mysql database and the map is populated with the markers. what i want to happen next is the lonlat stored for each marker is converted to an actual street address using reverse geo location and address appears on popup when marker clicked.

I have discovered Mapquest/Nominatim and a working example here -

http://jsfiddle.net/GWL7A/14/

But i cant figure out how to work it into my code. i have a function in my js file - 'downloadurl' which fetches the data from the server via xml file and uses a for loop to update all the markers / popups with the relevent information.

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {    
   var item_name = markers[i].getAttribute("item_name");
   var item_description = markers[i].getAttribute("item_description");
   var item_condition = markers[i].getAttribute("item_condition");
   var when_spotted = markers[i].getAttribute("when_spotted");
   var time_spotted = markers[i].getAttribute("time_spotted");
   var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")),
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude"))).transform(new   OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
   var file = markers[i].getAttribute("file");
   var html = "<b>" + item_name + "</b> <br/>" + item_description + "<br/>" + item_condition + "<br/>" + when_spotted + "<br/>" + time_spotted + "<br/>" + '<img src="'+file+'" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">';
   var size = new OpenLayers.Size(15,22);
   var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
   var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',size,offset);

   var features = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point,{
    description:   html 
   });

  vector.addFeatures(features);
 }
```

});

Somehow i need to work the reverse geolocation code into this block? or call a function from the block to do it. can anyone offer me any advice about how to do this? i cannot find a way to make the code in above example work in the context of my code. still pretty new to coding and lots to learn. if anyone can offer any guidance at all id be grateful. i also did extensive searching before coming here to post

Thanks

Comment: As it is written, I'm not sure you can, as you are using JSONP to do the geocoding, so you will have to update your markers asynchronously. Could you possibly combine everything into a single jsFiddle, as it is a bit hard to see exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just a hint: Nominatim can also return JSON which might be easier to process than XML.

Comment: Thanks for replies. i havent used jsfiddle before. i can paste the js and html pages straight in will that do?. the site also relies on php and mysql server so not sure how to make all that work

Comment: Im working on a solution with JSON which seems like it should work when i get it to parse the string of the URL correctly. thanks for pointing me in the right direction